# How to detect 2d polygon collision in Java?

Tags: java, 2d, polygon

Say I am making a simple asteroids game. There is a ship which is a java.geom rectangle2d, or whatever the import. There is one asteroid which is also a rectangle, but it is a different color. When the ship runs into the asteroid, I want it to be able to recognize it, and be able to print something out or show a JoptionPane. I learned a way of doing this with Areas, but it was really complicated and i heard somewhere that there was an easier way of doing this.

Any thoughts or links would be greatly appreciated!

Also, could I do this with PNGs?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use some third party engine for physics and collision detection. Like [Box2D](http://box2d.org) (you will need [JBox2D](http://www.jbox2d.org), the Java port of the engine). Writing collision code is interesting once, but it gets boring. Box2D is a very great engine. I use it in all my 2D platformer games.

Box2D is pretty advanced, but if you follow a good tutorial, you will be able to make it work for your situation.